# Java printwriter only writes one line

Tags: java, printwriter

My java program only writes one line to txt file.

code:Main:

```
package hu.hymosi.tut;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    frameworkcucc fw = new frameworkcucc();
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println(i);

        try {
            out = new PrintWriter("valtozok.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int kiirando = rand.nextInt();

        fw.writetotext(kiirando, out);
    }
}

}
```

frameworkcucc:

```
package hu.hymosi.tut;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class frameworkcucc {

public void writetotext(int write, PrintWriter writer) {
    writer.print(write + "\n");
}

}
```

If i run the program it just writes one line to my txt file.
What is the bug and how can i solve it?

Comment: EDIT: It creates a new line, just dont write numbers to it

Comment: Even if no value come to write since it's primitive it should print 0 at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `flush` your `PrintWriter` in order for the text to be added to your file.

Other observations:

- initialize your `Random` only once, outside the loop
- initialize your `PrintWriter` only once, outside the loop and check for nulls before the loop

Here is some slightly improved code (note that package etc. are changed).

```
package test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initialized before loop
        PrintWriter out = null;
        // proper naming convention
        Frameworkcucc fw = new Frameworkcucc();
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter("valtozok.txt");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // initialized before loop
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

            System.out.println(i);

            int kiirando = rand.nextInt();

            fw.writetotext(kiirando, out);
        }
        // flushing and closing
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}

class Frameworkcucc {

    public void writetotext(int write, PrintWriter writer) {
        writer.print(write + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new PrintWriter in every iteration. Move it outside the loop.

```
try {
            out = new PrintWriter("valtozok.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println(i);
        int kiirando = rand.nextInt();

        fw.writetotext(kiirando, out);
    }
}
```

Also its a good practice to cleanup the resources, it will flush the buffer too :

```
out.close()
```